# ASP.NET Image not showing as Resource

Tags: asp.net, image, resources

I have an image (Logo.png) that I'm using as a resource.  It's properties are Build Action-None.  For some reason it is not showing when I host it.  It works when I run it locally.  I read some articles about adding it to an Images folder but I can't imagine that it would be an issue where it's stored.

```
<img src="Resources/Logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the Build Action to 'Content'.  Image now displays.